# Python Requests Login 403

Tags: python, html, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to login to this website:

```
https://www.nike.com.br
```

First, I get the cookies with selenium, and then access a second url to get the visitor token cookie to pass it to the params of the login url

```
NIKE_LINK = "https://www.nike.com.br"
LOGIN_LINK = "https://unite.nike.com/login"
VISITOR_LINK = "https://unite.nike.com/akam/11/7e6e9f7d"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(NIKE_LINK)
cookies_home = driver.get_cookies()
driver.get(VISITOR_LINK)
cookies_visitor = driver.get_cookies()

#get the visitor token 
for cookie in cookies_visitor:
    if cookie['name'] == 'visitData':
        visitor = cookie['value']
        index= visitor.find('visitor') + 10
        for i in range(indice, len(visitor)):
            if visitor[i] == '"':
                break
        token = visitor[index:i]
```

Then I pass them to a Session with requests

```
session = requests.Session()

for cookie in cookie_home:
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], path=cookie['path'], domain=cookie['domain'])
```

And finally a try to login to the website using a POST request

```
params = (
    ('appVersion', '674'),
    ('experienceVersion', '674'),
    ('uxid', 'com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.brazil.web'),
    ('locale', 'pt_BR'),
    ('backendEnvironment', 'identity'),
    ('browser', 'Google Inc.'),
    ('os', 'undefined'),
    ('mobile', 'false'),
    ('native', 'false'),
    ('visit', '1'),
    ('visitor', token),
)

headers_login = {
    'authority': 'unite.nike.com.br',
    'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
    'origin': 'https://www.nike.com.br',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78',
    'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'referer': 'https://www.nike.com.br/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

data = '{"username":"%s'%email+'","password":"%s'%password+'","client_id":"_coe5BGx05K7qEETikSo_2YKClTo1qxI","ux_id":"com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.brazil.web","grant_type":"password"}'

response = session.post(LOGIN_LINK, headers=headers_login, params=params, json=data)
print(response.text)
```

But I get error 403

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;unite&#46;nike&#46;com&#47;login&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;4ec5d3ba&#46;1578601683&#46;770ee721
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: if you started with Selenium then why don't you use it for the rest?

Comment: to send json you don't have to create string - it will convert dictionary to json string automatically.

Comment: because selenium is way slower

Comment: but selenium is much easier

Comment: yes, I know hahaha but i'm trying something new

Comment: did you logged in with Selenium? It could help to see all headers and cookies which it needs. Maybe it uses AJAX to send data and server may check header `XMLHttpRequest`. In Selenium you used `Firefox()` but later you use User-Agent which can suggest Chrome browser. You could login few times and compare if some values are different in every login - maybe `"client_id"` has to be different in every login.

Comment: will check these things out, thanks!

Comment: BTW: you can also install local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and send all requests from browser and from code through proxy and you will see all data send to server - and you can compare requests from browser with requests from code. Maybe you will see differences which can make problem.

Comment: @furas I've tried doing this a while back with BurpSuite ([My StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239561/not-able-to-intercept-traffic-from-nike-com-login-request)) It seems that Nike has some crazy protection against it (never seen anything similar before)

Comment: @Fozoro it turns out sometimes I get the same error as you, but sometimes it does return 200 using BurpSuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, the reason for the 403 is because of the _abck cookies

Comment: Can you explain how to receive a correct _abck cookie?

Comment: Also looking for help with the cookies. Thanks

Comment: How this protection works - https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp